# CALayer and UIView display order

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a CATiledLayer within a UIView and the UIView also contains a subview.
How can I make sure that the subview is always drawn above the layer?

Most of the time I get the tile layer covering the subview.

Answer (score 11):

By default all layers (hence views) added in the last are drawn on the top. You can change the default with [`-insertSublayer:below:` and similar methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW92):

```
 [view.layer insertSublayer:tiledLayer below:thatSubview.layer]
```